# What is the process for combining 2 equations into 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$m$ and $n$ go from 0 to 1 and are known

if $[(m+n)/2] > 0.5$ then
$s= 2-m-n$
if $[(m+n)/2] \leq 0.5$ then
$s= m+n$

What process does one use to conclude that the above could be summarized as
$s= 1- |m+n-1|$

What would be a valid equivalent for $m$ and $n$ that go from 0 to 10 ?
A demonstration would be nice.

Comment: If (m+n)/2 > .5 then m + n > 1 and m+n - 1 > 0 so |m+n-1| = m+n -1.  So s = 2-m-n = 1-m-n+ 1 = 1 - (m+n -1) = 1 - |m+n-1|.  If (m+n)/2 <=.5 then (m+n) <= 1 so m+n - 1 = 0.  So |m+n -1| = -m - n +1.  So s = m + n = 1+(m + n -1) = 1 -(-m-n +1) = 1 -|m+n -1|

Comment: Since $m$ and $n$ only appear together, it would be easier (fewer letters to deal with) to denote say $x=m+n$, which ranges from 0 to 2 or to 20. It doesn't change anything, but solutions would look less cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

As @fleablood said in the comment,
$$
\frac{m + n}{2} > 0.5 \\
\implies m + n > 1 \\
\implies m + n - 1 > 0 \\
\implies \lvert m + n - 1 \rvert = m + n - 1
$$
Similarly, $\frac{m + n}{2} \leq 0.5 \implies \lvert m + n - 1 \rvert = - m - n + 1$. In both cases, if you manipulate the definitions of $s$ a little, you will see that you can come to $s = 1 - \lvert m + n - 1 \rvert$. The intuition can be obtained by thinking of the 'size' of $m$ and $n$ compared to 1, and whether it would be necessary to add or subtract them to get $s$.

For $0 < m, n < a$, just use the intuition hint above. Can you follow through after $\frac{m + n}{2} > \frac{a}{2}$?